# Eclipse and Maven compilation differences

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have added the simple code write to a file into an open source project (Saiku) that before my changes builds and compiles cleanly.

The program compiles cleanly in Centos 5.3 Eclipse (no red X's).

However, when rerunning the maven build script, the compiler errors are generated (Exhibit 1):

Does Maven compile java projects differently from Eclipse?

Exhibit 1:

```
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[67,8] illegal start of type
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[67,11] ';' expected
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[70,14] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[70,15] illegal start of type
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[71,14] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[73,14] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[75,11] illegal start of type
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[79,2] invalid method declaration; return type required
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[130,15] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[130,43] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/saiku-service/src/main/java/org/saiku/olap/util/formatter/HierarchicalCellSetFormatter.java:[131,8] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR]
```

Exhibit 2:

```
  import java.io.*; to the import section

  try {
     FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("/usr/local/dailycandy/biserver.txt");
     BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
     out.write("Hello Java");
     out.flush();
     //Close the output stream
     out.close();
  }
     catch (Exception e)
  {
 //Catch exception if any
 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the full class (including your changes)? I think the errors may be referencing context surrounding the snippet above.

Comment: Beau thanks for responding, copied class to http://pastebin.com/0G2hw4Va

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have added is not within a method/constructor/block etc. This is not valid Java, and thus does not compile.

You need to surround this with something like follows:

```
public void doSomething
{
    // Insert code here
}
```

Alternatively, you can place it in an existing method, or constructor, depending on when you need this code to execute.

Why Eclipse is not highlighting this error is beyond me. It would normally report this. Try refreshing your project or cleaning/rebuilding and you should see that it will fail to compile.